# Liferay Plugin 2.2

Tags: plugins, deployment, liferay

I have this problem:

I have two Liferay projects, one with the 1.6 plugin and one with the 2.2 plugin. When I deploy My project called IPF-Hook in the 1.6, it deploys with the name IPF-Hook.

The problem is when I deploy my project with the 2.2. It deploys with the name: IPF-Hook-portlet (it adds portlet).

Anyone knows something about that? thank you so much!

Comment: what does 1.6 and 2.2 refer to? Liferay plugins default to have these naming conventions as there are different steps that Liferay does for each plugin type. Instead of relying on the heuristics for Liferay to figure out what you have, following a naming convention makes the guessing process a bit more deterministic.

Comment: 1.6 and 2.2 are the liferay portlet versions. My question is if there is some configuration in the 2.2 plugin for take off the "-portlet" that the plugin ads to my project. Thanks for answer!

Comment: 2.2 as in "Liferay 2.2", released in October 2004? Or are these your internal release numbers, for custom plugins? I still have the feeling that I'm missing the obvious.

Comment: You forgot to link to all of the other places where you asked the same question. Please minimize the work that others do for you for free and add the crossreferences.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the comments (I still have no clue what versions you're talking about), now I'm seeing something that I've missed in the comments

Liferay uses a heuristic to detect the type of plugin that's deployed. This can be helped by naming a plugin `*-hook`, `*-portlet`, `*-theme` etc. . Typically you rather want to help Liferay than depend on the heuristic, thus the development environment tries its best to enforce this naming best practice.

Your hook seems to be named `*-Hook` (note the capital H) - rename it to have a lower case extension (`-hook`) and try again. Then it shouldn't be renamed any more.

If you're using the plugins sdk, check that this hook is indeed in the `hook` folder, not in the `portlets` folder.